# How to display pre-selected(default) value in drop down list according to the value fetch from database in jsp?

Tags: html, sql, jsp, jakarta-ee, drop-down-menu

I have a jsp page in which there is a drop-down list. The options in the drop down list comes from database. I need pre-selected option in the drop down list according to the value fetched from database by sql query.

Here is my code for jsp which has a drop down list and which fetches options from database.

```
 <select class="form-control col-sm-7" name="leavedropdown" style="width: 31% ; margin-right:-20%" >             
 <option>--Select Group--</option>                                         
<%  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

//step2 create  the connection object  
Connection con17=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","system","system");

PreparedStatement  psmt17= con17.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM LEAVE_TYPE");
 ResultSet rs17=psmt17.executeQuery();

while(rs17.next()) {

%>

 <option value="<%= rs17.getString(2)%>"><%= rs17.getString(2)%> </option>

 <% } %>
 </select>
```

Now I wrote this code above the current select tag to fetch value of a record which should be pre-selected in drop down list

```
PreparedStatement  psmt18= con18.prepareStatement("SELECT DISTINCT LEAVE_TYPE FROM EMPLOYEE_LEAVE where lid='LV00001'");
 ResultSet rs18=psmt18.executeQuery();
 %>
```

How should I use this value to match into drop down list and display it as pre-selected option in it?

Comment: First of all it is not advisable to make connections in a jsp.Secondly user selected attribute in <option> tag to check if value of field matches option value

Comment: JSP should not have any of these code.